# How to set Grpc Connection max limit in Java?

Tags: java, session, connection, limit, grpc

is there any limit of grpc connection? If its limitless, how can I set max limit number of grpc connection? (Java)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I am afraid this is not an option at the moment. There is an open issue in the grpc-java repo where you can track the progress. https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/1886